# Do triggers run after a record triggered flow?

Tags: trigger, visual-workflow

I have looked at various documentation and articles to get an explicit answer to this question, including the order-of-execution article (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm).

- I want to know if triggers run after a field update from a record triggered flow that is configured to run after the record is saved i.e step 14 in that article.
- Looking at that article gives the impression that the answer is "No", but it would be good to have this explicitly confirmed.

So does anyone have access to a document or article which explicitly addresses this?

Comment: is this a field update on the same $Record or some other record?

Comment: On the same record

Comment: then see the "recursive save" decision block outcome `YES` on the [diagram](https://architect.salesforce.com/assets/images/Salesforce-Order-Of-Execution-Diagram.png)